# Issues reading cells using map() in a range in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that works perfectly when assigning it on a per-cell basis, but when I try to create an array using the map() function, cell values are not being read properly. Can anyone help on this?

I've tried to read up on this and it might have something to do with Google Sheets map() function not being able to handle certain scenarios because all calcs are being done server-side? Not sure.

Anyway, I'm trying to read dates from one column, and see whether there was a discount in another column, and based on the date and discount token "DSC", return a percent discount value: 25% for or 30% if between 2 dates.

Picture of no 30% values in 3rd column[image]

Below is the code for the working function (assigned to each cell) and non-working map() function assigned to a range then a Google Sheets link:

```
// ==================================== Using .map 
/**
@customfunction
*/
function Disc_Perc_Map (input1, input2){ // input1 is product ID column, input2 is Date
  var Date_1_a = Date.parse(String("1/3/2017")) ;// put start date of discount change here
  var Date_1_b = Date.parse(String("1/4/2017")) ;// put end date of discount change here
  var Disc_Def = .25;
  var Disc_1 = .30;
  if (input1.map){ // Checks if array 
    return input1.map(Disc_Perc_Map);   // added along with added brace at end
  } else { 

    // Main part of code 
    if (String(input1).indexOf(",") >-1) { // if there are commas
      Cell_Array = input1.split(",");
      Cell_Len = input1.split(',').length;
      var Date_Num = Date.parse(String(input2));
      if (Date_Num >= Date_1_a && Date_Num <= Date_1_b){
        return Disc_1;
      } else {
        return Disc_Def;
      }
    } else {                          // if there are NO commas
      return "";
      //Cell_Len = 1;
    }
  }
}


// ==================================== without using .map
/**
@customfunction
*/
function Disc_Perc_No_Map(input1, input2) { // input1 is product ID column, input2 is Date
  var Date_1_a = Date.parse(String("1/3/2017")) ;// put start date of discount change here
  var Date_1_b = Date.parse(String("1/4/2017")) ;// put end date of discount change here
  var Disc_Def = .25;
  var Disc_1 = .30;

  // Main part of code 
  if (String(input1).indexOf(",") > -1) { // if there are commas
    Cell_Array = input1.split(",");
    Cell_Len = input1.split(',').length;
    var Date_Num = Date.parse(String(input2));
    if (Date_Num >= Date_1_a && Date_Num <= Date_1_b){
      return Disc_1;
    } else {
      return Disc_Def;
    }
  } else {   // if there are NO commas
    return "";
    //Cell_Len = 1;
  }         
}
```

[Link to example Google Sheets:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zp_ux3IbU4iatnSAtYdtkePQhZ6iURNtms3LFJatOY/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help great appreciated.

Comment: Google Apps Script isn't JavaScript, though it's very, very, very similar to JavaScript circa 2007 or 2008. Are you sure arrays have the `map` function (which was added in 2009)?

Comment: Obviously, in your own code you can use any indentation strategy you like, but when asking others to spend their time helping you, please take the time to format and indent the code in a reasonable, consistent, readable way.

Comment: Thanks TJ. I'm new to all this. Sorry about the formatting. Not exactly sure what I did wrong formatting-wise. I'l update the tags to Google Apps Script if it will let, me.

Comment: Regarding your question about being sure if arrays have the map function... not sure how to answer that. I can get the Map function to work across a range as an array. But when trying to *read* from another cell within a map function, I'm having issues. Then again, I am a newbie, so... I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint on the first line of Disc_Perc_Map (by clicking the line number in Script Editor), executing the script in debug mode (by using the bug instead of the play symbol), and then using "Step Into" to advance line-by-line. This should let you see what gets passed into where, and what the arrays look like, etc. Performing this kind of debugging task is invaluable for determining how a script or program is going awry.

Comment: Thanks tehhowch!! That did yield and error... and thanks for showing me this... I was flying blind. I got this error message with a host of details that I'll have to learn how to decipher. But basically it says:

**Cannot read property "map" from undefined. (line 14, file "Code")**.  

Thanks again!

Comment: Also, when comparing the Debug from the non-map() version, there were not errors and no undefined variables. The code is identical with the exception of the 3 lines of code related to map().

Comment: Thanks  I'-'I, I'm new to the GS debug mode, but when I run the "working" vs non-working map() version, I seem to be getting the same undefined verbose listings in debug columns, however the functions works in the non-map() version. hmmm

Comment: I'-'I .... how would I map **both** input1 and input2 to the map() function? I googled it but get a ton of google Map api hits.

Comment: @I'-'I That re: notifying people.  What is input1 defined as? (Newbie answer forthcoming...) I'm not sure. I mean, it's reading a cell that could be a number or also a string. I do treat it as a string with the String() function. Not sure I'm understanding the Q. I did include the non-map() function below the code of the Map() in the OP. Sorry for being so dense. But I am learning... slowly :)

Comment: @I'-'I It shows it as Undefined. However, as I step through the debug, other variables updated. I hope I'm answering what you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the reason of issue is as follows.

- When `Disc_Perc_Map()` do the callback, `input2` becomes the index of `input1.map()`.

  - So the values of `input2` inputted from the custom function is removed from the running script.

In order to avoid this issue, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Backup `input2` and use in the callback.
- In order to use the backed up `input2`, add a counter.

  - Retrieve the date value using the counter.

#### Modified script :

```
var cnt = -1; // Added
var input2bk; // Added

function Disc_Perc_Map (input1, input2){ // input1 is product ID column, input2 is Date

  if (isNaN(input2)) input2bk = input2; // Added

  var Date_1_a = Date.parse(String("1/3/2017")) ;// put start date of discount change here
  var Date_1_b = Date.parse(String("1/4/2017")) ;// put end date of discount change here
  var Disc_Def = .25;
  var Disc_1 = .30;

  if (input1.map){ // Checks if array 
    return input1.map(Disc_Perc_Map);   // added along with added brace at end
  } else {

    cnt += 1; // Added

    // Main part of code 
    if (String(input1).indexOf(",") > -1) { // if there are commas
      Cell_Array = input1.split(",");
      Cell_Len = input1.split(',').length;
      var Date_Num = Date.parse(String(input2bk[cnt][0])); // Modified
      if (Date_Num >= Date_1_a && Date_Num <= Date_1_b){
        return Disc_1;
      } else {
        return Disc_Def;
      }
    } else {   // if there are NO commas
      return "";
      //Cell_Len = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Another pattern :

As an another pattern, how about this modification? This is also the same result with above.

```
function Disc_Perc_Map (input1, input2) { // input1 is product ID column, input2 is Date
  var Date_1_a = Date.parse(String("1/3/2017")) ;// put start date of discount change here
  var Date_1_b = Date.parse(String("1/4/2017")) ;// put end date of discount change here
  var Disc_Def = .25;
  var Disc_1 = .30;
  return input1.map(function(e, i) {
    // Main part of code 
    if (String(e[0]).indexOf(",") > -1) { // if there are commas
      Cell_Array = e[0].split(",");
      Cell_Len = e[0].split(',').length;
      var Date_Num = Date.parse(String(input2[i][0])); // Modified
      if (Date_Num >= Date_1_a && Date_Num <= Date_1_b) {
        return [Disc_1];
      } else {
        return [Disc_Def];
      }
    } else {   // if there are NO commas
      return [""];
      //Cell_Len = 1;
    }
  });
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Fantastic!! **Fix #2 worked like a charm as-is.** Your first fix I was not ale to get to work. Maybe I did something wrong. I tried it with the 2 added vars before and after the function declaration and got an error: **Error TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.** But for sure your 2nd solution worked!! Thanks so much... I will have to sit down and thoroughly wrap my head around what you did! :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand why we need this: `input2[i][0]` when we don't need the same format for `e[0]`. Obviously we do, otherwise it doesn't work...  I'll have to keep thinking about it... still hasn't quite sunken in :)

Comment: @Thonex1234 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Do you ask about "Another pattern :"? If it's so, ``e[0]`` and ``input2[i][0]`` mean the element of ``input1`` and ``input2``, respectively. I used the index ``i`` for ``input1`` because both the indexes of ``input1`` and ``input2`` are synchronized in your situation. And using ``i``, the elements of ``input2`` are retrieved. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: Thanks you! Your understanding is 100% correct. I just need to experiment so I can fully understand. Sorry.. sometimes I'm slow :)

Comment: @Thonex1234 I think that I'-'I's comment is useful for you. When you have any questions, feel free to tell them.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for the additional information and your support!